# Is there a way to open .ipynb file in Jupyterlab which is being stored in network mapped drive?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to open python file which is currently stored in Network mapped drive through jupyterlab interface, but I am not able to navigate to that folder.

Is there a way to do that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4daIa.png)

Comment: Does it work to open your anaconda prompt, then `cd \d z:` and then start your notebook with `jupyter notebook`?

Comment: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/jupyter-fs might be of your interest

Comment: Hi @FlyingTeller, I tried cd and the path it doesn't work and gave "CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories." Error. But pushd //path worked and then opening jupyter-lab via command line helped me access the folder. Thanks for direction!

Comment: Since you have mapped it as a drive `Z`, you should have been able to `cd` to the drive `z` with the command I suggested. Did that not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried cd and the path it doesn't work and gave "CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories." Error. But 'pushd //path', instead of 'cd //path' worked and then opening jupyter-lab via command line helped me access the folder.